# How to calculate the geometric mean titer (GMT) of titers from a haemagglutination assay (influenza)?

Tags: immunology, influenza

I got a list of Influenza-specific antibody titers from a hemagglutination inhibition assay.

They look like this:

- `40`
- `640`
- `160`
- `<10`

[One site](https://www.aasv.org/shap/issues/v10n1/v10n1p39.html) says: *“The swine influenza HI scale is geometric: 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640 (successive values increase by a factor of 2). The geometric scale is logarithmic. It is best to express an average influenza HI titer as a geometric mean. A geometric mean is calculated by averaging the logarithms of the test values and then converting the mean to a real number. This prevents a few obviously high positive values from making the mean unrealistically large.”*

What does that mean for my sample? How do I deal with `<10` in this calculation? This is surely not rocket science, but honestly I don’t get it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Typically "<10" is converted to a number that is below the limit of detection; often "9".  After that simply following the instructions you have yields a GMT of 77.9.  If you are using spreadsheet apps such as Excel or Google Sheets, they almost certainly offer "GEOMEAN" functions which will give the number directly.